# Mongoose Find One on Nested Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get info from an object that is nested within an object in Mongo. The data structure looks like this:

```
Card{
    _id;
    contributors: [
        {
            name;
            _id;
        },
        {
            name;
            _id;
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my attempt at accessing a specific 'contributor' in the 'contributors' array.

```
Card.findOne({_id: cardId, "contributor._id": contributorId},
    (err, contributor) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500);
            res.send({status: "error", message: "sass overload"});
            return;
        }
    console.log(contributor);
    res.send(contributor);
});
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection

Comment: Why semicolons instead of commas?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `"contributors._id"` not `"contributor._id"`

The name of the field in your Model is `contributors` not `contributor`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15025475)

Comment: It is the answer though. I had a similar issue a short while ago.

Comment: be specific about your answer tho.. so that other users who will get same problem can understand easily.

Comment: May be you can expand the answer and mention the place where the changes need to be added.